# Why the "cannot select from a type variable"

Tags: java, generics, builder

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class A {

    public String att;

    public static abstract class Builder<T extends A> {

        public T a;

        public abstract T build();

        public T.Builder setAtt(String a) {
            this.a.att = a;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class A1 extends A {

    public static class Builder extends A.Builder<A1> {

        public Builder() {
            this.a = new A1();
        }

        public A1 build() {
            return this.a;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class A2 extends A {

    public String subAtt;

    public static class Builder extends A.Builder<A2> {

        public Builder() {
            this.a = new A2();
        }

        public A2 build() {
            return this.a;
        }

        public Builder setSubAtt(String subAtt) {
            a.subAtt = subAtt;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get "*cannot select from a type variable*" error on the `A.setAtt`?

Type erasure shouldn't apply. `T` is either `A1` or `A2` but this is known at compile-time.

How should I return the subclass builder then? My main objective is to be able to do setter after setter mixing subclass and superclass.

Comment: Could you please share the code that triggers the error? Pasting your code into an IDE does not trigger a compile error.

Comment: Type erasure does apply since one could easily make another class that extends A from outside, and your system would break.

Comment: Is there a way to do this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marko explained, you cannot simply use 'T.Builder' and expect the compiler to determine the nested class of an unknown type.

What you can do is to force a subclass of `Builder` to identify itself:

```
public class A
{

    public String att;    

    public static abstract class Builder<T extends A, U extends Builder<T, U>>
    {

        public T a;

        public abstract T build();

        public U setAtt(String a)
        {
            this.a.att = a;
            return getBuilder();
        }

        public abstract U getBuilder();        


    }        
}
```

```
public class A1 extends A
{

    public static class Builder extends A.Builder<A1, A1.Builder>
    {

        public Builder()
        {
            this.a = new A1();
        }

        @Override
        public A1 build()
        {
            return this.a;
        }


        @Override
        public A1.Builder getBuilder()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

This way a Statement like

```
A1 build = new A1.Builder().setAtt("x").build();
```

would work.

Comment: An additional note to the field `a` in the abstract `Builder` class: To avoid NPEs when when setting the superclass' attribut you may consider also getting `a` via a getter: `public abstract T getA()`.

Comment: The bound on `U` is unnecessary: `class Builder<T extends A, U>` works just as well

Comment: The bound on `U` is necessary when you want to be able to use the method `setAtt` of the supertype(s) in any phase of the build process rather than only as first call.

Comment: It will still work on not the first call in the example you gave, with `new A1.Builder()...`

Comment: Yes, but with the bounds you prohibit subclasses of `A` with builders that dont't provide subclasses of `Builder` with `getBuilder()`. Without the bounds, any `Object` would be possible there, eg. `String`. This causes issues when trying to iterate over a collection of builders `Collection<? extends A.Builder> col = ...`. Then you only can use the first setter of the superclass and get an `Object` in return.

Comment: In any case there must be a subclass of `Builder`, because `Builder` is abstract. Even if the subclass is represented by a type parameter, the type parameter can be bound where such a relationship is needed. A homogeneous collection of one type of builder can make it work using generics. A heterogenous collection of different types of builder is a weird case that I don't think is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

This cannot possibly work:

```
T.Builder
```

Since `T` is a type *variable* and therefore not bound to any specific type, you cannot expect the compiler to resolve a nested type of an unknown type.

> `T` is either `A1` or `A2` but this is known at compile-time.

This assumption is wrong: imagine you offer your code as a JAR and another developer uses it, introducing his own subclass of `A`. If Java code was compiled under the assumption of a closed world, Maven would be a most useless service.

The assumption is also irrelevant: you would need a quite more sophisticated type system to work out what general type `T.Builder` conforms to.